# How to join dataframes (from a collection of Datasets)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I was searching and figuring out the best way to join `n` Spark dataframes.

Example `List(df1,df2,df3,dfN)` where all `df` have a date where I can join on.

Recursion ?

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
List(df1,df2,df3,dfN).reduce((a, b) => a.join(b, joinCondition))
```

Comment: I have done it with recursion. But it seems clear that way. 
`def recursiveJoinOnDate(list: List[DataFrame]): DataFrame = {
    if (list.isEmpty){
      null
    }else if(list.size >1){
      list.head.join(recursiveJoinOnDate(list.tail),"Date")
    }else
      list.head
  }`

Answer (score 1):

I am writing the same answer as above for pyspark users.

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce
dfslist #list of all dataframes that you want to join
mergedDf = reduce(lambda df1,df2 : df1.join(df2, [df1.joinKey == df2.joinKey ], "outer").select("*", coalesce(df1.joinKey, df2.joinKey).alias("joinKey")).drop(df1.joinKey ).drop(df2.joinKey ), dfslist )
```