# pyspark joining more than 2 dataframes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose i have 100 of data frames and how can i combine it into single one having all the columns. my data frames is looking like,

```
id  name  marks
00  abc   70
01  def   67
02  ghi   68
03  jkl    90


id  name  class
00  abc A
01  def    B
02  ghi B
03  jkl    A


id  name  std
00  abc    1
01  def    2
02  ghi    3
03  jkl    4

id  name  city
00  abc    mex
01  def    nyc
02  ghi    ind
03  jkl    aus
```

So i have more than 50 data frames so last columns is changing each time.

So my question is how can i make single resultant dataframe which will look like below,

```
 id  name  marks  class  std  city
 00  abc    70      A     1    mex
 01  def     67     B     2    nyc
 02  ghi     68     B     3    la
 03  jkl     90     A     4    aus
```

Answer (score 0):

You could join couple of them using nested spark SQL query, however it will take plenty of time to join fifty of them.

Comment: is it possible to convert this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40603989/join-multiple-dataframes-spark  into pyspark???